# Firefox/Chrome was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular10, angular-unit-test

After running *ng test* in my local angular(v10) project, all the test cases are executing successfully and the browser is also getting launched and I am able to see the green dots but at the last moment browser is killed with the following warning in my command prompt

[image]

karma.config.js

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-firefox-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine-html-reporter',
      'karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter',
      '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma',
      'karma-junit-reporter',
      'karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter'
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    sonarQubeUnitReporter: {
      sonarQubeVersion: 'LATEST',
      outputFile: 'reports/ut_report.xml',
      overrideTestDescription: true,
      testPaths: ['./ng-app'],
      testFilePattern: '.spec.ts',
      useBrowserName: false
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'angular_junit_reporter', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      outputFile: 'karma_unit_test', // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
      suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
      useBrowserName: true, // add browser name to report and classes names
      nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
      classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
      properties: {}, // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
      xmlVersion: null // use '1' if reporting to be per SonarQube 6.2 XML format
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev',
      codeCoverage: true
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
                ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
                : ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'sonarqubeUnit', 'junit'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Firefox'],
    singleRun: true,
    restartOnFileChange: false,
    captureTimeout: 210000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserDisconnectTimeout : 210000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout : 210000
  });
};
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your values as:-
autoWatch: true,
singleRun: false,

Optional change, it may or may not required
restartOnFileChange: true

Remove space before colon:-
browserDisconnectTimeout: 210000,
browserNoActivityTimeout: 210000

Answer (score 0):

For me it works, after running the test with watch true.

```
"test": "ng test --code-coverage --watch=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed after

- Removing node_modules folder.
- Running npm install.

Apparently karma files got corrupted and couldn't be fixed automatically.